# Reading Zillow XML File with PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, zillow

I have an XML file I want to read, but can't seem to make sense of it.

To access the file I pulled you can type in:

http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz1gyo1562s5n_6sext&address=155+Demar+Blvd&citystatezip=Canonsburg%2C+PA

I'm doing this through PHP, so my code looks like:

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Hellow World</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php
$zillow_id = 'X1-ZWz1gyo1562s5n_6sext';

$search = '155 Demar Blvd';
$citystate = 'Canonsburg PA';
$address = urlencode($search);
$citystatezip = urlencode($citystate);

$url = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=$zillow_id&address=$address&citystatezip=$citystatezip";

$result = file_get_contents($url);
$data = simplexml_load_string($result);

echo $data->response->results->result->lotSizeSqFt . "<br>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I had expected this code to result in the printout of the lot size - in square feet - to the screen. No dice.

However, the line of code:

```
echo $data->response->results->result->zpid . "<br>";
```

returns the expected value for the zpid parameter: 49785503.

In an ideal world the line of code:

```
echo $data->response->results->result->lotSizeSqFt . "<br>";
```

would return: 9000.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `lotSizeSqFt` isn't in the result set

Comment: Seems to be to me, but not sure what you mean by "result set".

<response>
     <results>
          <result>
               <zpid>49785503</zpid>
               <links>...</links>
               <address>...</address>
               <FIPScounty>42125</FIPScounty>
               <useCode>SingleFamily</useCode>
               <taxAssessmentYear>2018</taxAssessmentYear>
               <taxAssessment>170100.0</taxAssessment>
               <yearBuilt>1948</yearBuilt>
               <lotSizeSqFt>9000</lotSizeSqFt>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong endpoint in your code.

Your endpoint:
`http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm`

The correct endpoint:
`http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm`

Using the `GetDeepSearchResults` will return the results you're looking for.

Comment: Didn't even notice the mismatch in my own code... wow.  Thank you.  I will except this as an answer.  Much appreciated.